# Edit applied resource configuration with kubectl apply -k

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-efs

I'm applying aws-efs-csi driver like this on a kubernates cluster:

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=release-1.0"
```

I need to edit the configuration file to add credentials for pulling docker images.

I couldn't find ways to edit via kubectl edit ..

This is the pod in the kube-system namespace:

```
# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                READY STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
...
kube-system   efs-csi-node-xxssqr  3/3   Running   0          69d
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a daemonset.

`kubectl -n kube-system edit ds/efs-csi-node`

Comment: Thanks XciD!
That was exactly it!